# how i cover ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ScheduleFlag') == 'True' in test class

Tags: unit-test, class

```
 if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ScheduleFlag') == 'True'){
            schId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('schId');
            schReport = [Select Id,Report_Name__c,Selected_Fields__c,Labels__c  from Schedule_Report__c where Id = :schId];
            allFields = schReport.Selected_Fields__c;
            allLabels = New List<string>();
            for(string lab :schReport.Labels__c.split(',')){
              allLabels.add(lab.trim());  
            }
            ScheduleFlag = true;
            directSchedule = true;
            WeeklyFlag = true;
            userList = new list<SelectOption>();
            for(user usr : [SELECT Id,IsActive,Name,Email FROM User where IsActive = true]){
                userList.add(new SelectOption(usr.Email,usr.Name));
            }

            //Next4();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your unit test, first set the value:

```
Test.setCurrentPage(Page.myVFPage);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('ScheduleFlag','True');
```

And then call the controller method:

```
MyController con = new MyController();
con.myMethodThatUsesParameter();
```

As always, make sure you validate the the output from this method is whatever you're expecting.

Comment: Great minds think alike! You JUST beat me to it... :)

Comment: @DavidSchach Yeah, what a coincidence. You can have this one if you want it, though. I don't really need the rep.

Comment: Not Working. still not cover that line

Comment: ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(ObjReport);
        ReportGenerationNewCtrl ObjClass = new  ReportGenerationNewCtrl(sc);
        
        PageReference pageRef = Page.ReportGenerationNew;
       ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('ScheduleFlag','True');
       // ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('schId',string.valueof(ObjReport.id));
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

Comment: @ArvindTyagi The order of operations is important...

Comment: https://c.cs77.visual.force.com/apex/ReportGenerationNew?EditFlag=true&schId=a1C0t0000009P9FEAU geeting this id in url

Comment: Too late @sfdcfox - you got it!

Answer (score 1):

In your test class, you'll need to set the current page and its parameters:

```
Test.setCurrentPage(Page.TestPage);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('ScheduleFlag', 'True');
```

Then instantiate the controller as usual.